# How to properly escape string to test in shell?

Tags: shell, busybox

I have the following function:

```
testit()
{
[ "$1" == "OK" ] && echo "good" || echo "bad"
}
```

but it doesn't work as expected. I can call it with:

```
testit 'OK' #good
testit 'abc' #bad
```

but when I call it with:

```
testit '('
```

it fails with: "sh: closing paren expected". I've quoted the string to test, so why it acts like there are no quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in your shell implementation. I have tested your code on the latest CentOS and it works fine.

```
testit '('
bad

 sh -version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: my shell is busybox shell.. isn't that why it doesn't work?
`BusyBox v1.17.1 (2012-04-04 20:02:59 PDT) multi-call binary.`

Comment: Yes, I suspect that might be the problem.

Comment: but I can't change the shell.. is there any way to workaround it?

Comment: You might be able to use a regex to remove/escape the problem characters but this depends on your implementation.

Comment: I've used search&replace to replace the stupid paren. Thanks for the idea! 'Cus there are no better answers, you deserve the green mark.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly workaround:

```
if [ "x$1" = "xOK" ]; ...
```